# Limit of $a_{n+1}= \frac{n}{n+1} a_n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, induction

I think that this sequence 
$$a_{n+1}= \frac{n}{n+1} a_n$$

can be rewritten as $$a_n= \frac{1}{n+1}a_0.$$
Therefore the limit should be $0$.

But my proof by induction turns out wrong. Is my idea correct? And how can I prove it?

Comment: Aren't you given *at least* what $\;a_0\;$ is?!

Comment: the limit should be zero, no matter what $a_0$ is.

Comment: @Timbuc No, I'm not given $a_0$

Comment: In fact $a_n = \frac{0}{n} a_0$, so just $a_n = 0$.

Comment: Adayah grabbed it, imo: *if* that's really the given definition and it begins with $\;a_0\;$ , then the sequence is identically zero, since: $$a_0=\text{whatever}\;,\;\;a_1=a_{0+1}=\frac01a_0=0\;,\;\;a_2=\frac12\cdot0=0\;,\ldots$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $na_n=b_n$. Then, one has
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}a_n\Rightarrow (n+1)a_{n+1}=na_n\Rightarrow b_{n+1}=b_n.$$
So, $b_n=b_1=a_1$. Hence, $na_n=a_1$, i.e. $a_n=\frac{a_1}{n}$.